# Change content of table according to week number

Tags: php, date

I am working on a script for a drivers license website, and I need to make a calendar like table for the students, so they can see when they have which lesson.

Right now we are updating the table manually, but I would like to make a script so it can do it automatically.

The table looks like this: (By the way, its a HTML table).

```
+----------+--------+---------+-----------+----------+--------+
| Week Nr. | Monday | Tuesday | Wednesday | Thursday | Friday |
+----------+--------+---------+-----------+----------+--------+
|    17    |   14   |    1    |     16    |     2    |        |
+----------+--------+---------+-----------+----------+--------+
|    18    |    4   |    1    |     6     |          |        |
+----------+--------+---------+-----------+----------+--------+
|    19    |    8   |    1    |     11    |          |        |
+----------+--------+---------+-----------+----------+--------+
|    20    |   14   |    1    |     16    |     2    |        |
+----------+--------+---------+-----------+----------+--------+
```

Lets say its this week (Week 17), it has its own set of lessons for every day, except Friday, which is the same for every week. Then it is the week after, which has its own set of lessons, and then it is 3 weeks after, which again has its own set of lessons. Then the 4th week, it start all over, with the same set as week 17, because its a 3 week program, over and over again.

What i want to do is that it automatically updates the table, so it shows the current week number. Then let us say that it is next week now, the table should have automatically update it self to show the current week and its set of lesson numbers.

The numbers under the column "Week Nr." are the week numbers, and the numbers under the day names are the lesson numbers.

So next week it should look like this:

```
+----------+--------+---------+-----------+----------+--------+
| Week Nr. | Monday | Tuesday | Wednesday | Thursday | Friday |
+----------+--------+---------+-----------+----------+--------+
|    18    |    4   |    1    |     6     |          |        |
+----------+--------+---------+-----------+----------+--------+
|    19    |    8   |    1    |     11    |          |        |
+----------+--------+---------+-----------+----------+--------+
|    20    |   14   |    1    |     16    |     2    |        |
+----------+--------+---------+-----------+----------+--------+
|    21    |    4   |    1    |     6     |          |        |
+----------+--------+---------+-----------+----------+--------+
```

Is there anybody who could give me a hint on how to do that with PHP. I have tried everything I knkw, but I just cant get it right.

Comment: `echo date('W');` will give you the current week number (see PHP's [`date`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) function for more).

Answer (score 1):

This is not exactly what you want, but it could be a good starting point. Just modify it to print out the HTML tags.

```
//Set a counter for the lessons
$j = 0;
//Loop through the weeks of the year
for ($i = 1; $i <= 52; $i++) {
    echo "Week: ".$i."<br>";
    echo "This weeks  lessons: " . $j."<br>";
    //Incrase counter
    $j++;
    if ($j % 3 === 0) {
        //Reset counter if need
        echo "<hr>";
        $j = 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the idea. Yeah it helps alot, now i need to figure out how to assign the different lesson numbers to the diffrent weeks. Changed the $i = 1; to $i = date("W");, to get the exact week number to start from. Also changed the $i <= 52; to $i <= $i <= $weekNr + 3;